# Is the following Itô-Integral not zero?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

is the following statement true:

$$\int_0^T t \, dW(t) \neq 0$$

I need it for a counter-example, that one can not change the order of integration between $dW$ and $dP(\omega)$. I thought of taking the following:
$$ E\left[\int_0^T W^2(t) \, dW(t)\right]=0 \neq \int_0^T t \, dW(t)=\int_0^T E[W^2(t)] \, dW(t)$$
Intuitively it should be correct but how can I proof it? Applying the defintion of the Itô-Integral?

Answer (score 3):

The random variable
$$
X=\int_0^Tt\mathrm dW_t
$$
is normal with mean zero and variance
$$
\int_0^Tt^2\mathrm dt\ne0,
$$
hence $$P(X=0)=0.$$

Comment: Why is $P(X=0)=0$? I'm probably thinking to complicated right now...

Comment: Because no gaussian random variable with nonzero variance has an atom at zero. (Yes it may help to remember that "underneath" quite a few of these Brownian integrals there is nothing but a gaussian random variable.)

Comment: On a personal note and from an aesthetics point of view, I find quite satisfying that the other answer on the page is duly upvoted although it is deeply wrong starting from its line 2, while this one has been downvoted. A negative score would be even more pleasing but +1/-1 is already nice...

Comment: Oops... good things never last, +2/-1 now (joking, of course).

Answer (score 2):

What we need:

$$\int_0^t s \, dW_s$$

Take Ito for $f(t,W_t)=tW_t$:

$$f=f(0,W_0)+\int_0^t\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}ds+\int_0^t\frac{\partial f}{\partial W_s}dW_s+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial W_s^2}d[W_s,W_s]$$

$$tW_t=\int_0^t W_s  ds + \int_0^t s dW_s $$

Then

$$\int_0^t s \, dW_s =tW_t-\int_0^t W_s  ds$$

Where the later integral as you can see [here](http://www.wiley.com/legacy/wileychi/brownianmotioncalculus/supp/BMC_slides_3_8.pdf) is a normal with mean $0$ and variance $\frac{t^3}{3}$

Comment: Itô's formula yields $\displaystyle W_t^2=t+2\int_0^tW_s\,\mathrm dW_s$ (with the formula that you applied, $W_t^2-t$ would not be a martingale).

Comment: @Ian thanks now is fixed :)

Comment: Note that the integral is with respect to $W$, not $t$...

Comment: @Ian my mistake :( I think I should delete the answer

Comment: @Ian thanks for pointing my error. Now I think all is in order

Comment: Yes I think everything is correct now, so I removed my downvote. However, I don't really think using Itô's formula simplifies things since you can check that the Wiener integral $\displaystyle\int_0^ts\,\mathrm dW_s$ follows a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $t^3/3$ directly.