# Simple differential equation and Integral Ito

Tags: stochastic-integrals

With stochastic differential equation dx(t) = dW (t), and knowing that all integrals occurring are integral Ito. Witch variable changes y = tx. How I can prove?

*integral between 0 and t[sdW(s)] = tW(t) - [integral between 0 and t[sdW(s)] W(s) ds]*

thanks

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/801698/

Answer (score 0):

Let $X(t)$ be the process governed by the Stochastic Differential Equation

$$dX(t)=dW(t)$$

where $W$ is a Wiener process.  If $Y(t)=tX(t)$, then by Ito's Lemma, we have

$$\begin{align}
d(tW(t))&=W(t)dt+tdX(t)\\\\
&=W(t)dt+tdW(t) \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Integrating $(1)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^t d(sW(s))&=tW(t)\\\\
&=\int_0^t W(t)dt+\int_0^tsdW(s)\\\\
\end{align}$$